# How to reference a c# class library project(not dll) from a different solution

Tags: c#, .net, class-library

My project is in solution1. I want to refer a project from solution2. I could refer the dll successfully, but not the project.

I can not add the other project to my solution. In that case how can I add it as a project reference. Need some suggestions.

I have added the reference manual in the csproj file, but the build is failing.

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Common\Project2.csproj">
      <Project>{78cd0a60-06fb-4941-323e-337f0e43c693}</Project>
      <Name>Project2</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Comment: what is wrong with adding reference as `.dll`

Comment: You can add the project itself to your solution https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx

Comment: For consistency with other project, as they are already using such references.

Answer (score 2):

Place both of your project in same folder (class library project and your current project)- *recommended but not necessary*

1) Right click your solution file and click **Add --> Existing Project** --> go to the folder of class library project and select project file.

2) Once the project is added to the solution, you need to add reference to your present application.

3) Now right click your project and click **Add Reference**

4) Select solution and check your class library project and **Press OK.**

5) **Rebuild your solution**.

6) You can now use classes and objects of class library with the use of **using** statement at top of your .cs files

Comment: You don't need them in the same folder, the projects can be anywhere as long as they are in the same solution, but this is how I'd do it.

Comment: @PeterMorris I Agree.

Comment: My solution has already too many projects. As per the functionality of the project it is placed in a different solution. So I can not add it to the required solution.

Comment: @maverick Just one more small thing I changed "Using" to "using" and bolded it to indicate a keyword